# C# Treap implementation

Tags: c#, tree, library, heap

I recently developed a simple [treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) data structure in C#. In the future, I may have the class extend `IDictionary`. For now, I only expose a public accessor and a delete method.

```
    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return Get(root, key).Value; }
        set { root = Set(root, new Node(key, value)); }
    }
```

The data structure is generic and maintains the key-value pairs in an inner `Node` class. Internally, the tree is organized both by the binary search requirement on `Node.Key` and the heap invariant requirement on `Node.Priority`.

```
public class BinaryTreap<TKey, TValue> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    [DebuggerDisplay("Key={Key}, Priority={Priority}")]
    /// <summary>Represents a Node in a BinaryTreap</summary>
    class Node
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();

        public readonly int Priority;
        public readonly TKey Key;
        public readonly TValue Value;

        public Node Left, Right;

        public Node(TKey key, TValue value, 
            Node left = null, Node right = null)
        {
            Priority = random.Next(); Key = key; 
            Value = value; Left = left; Right = right;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Tree root, organized as min-heap/BST</summary>
    private Node root;
}
```

The methods `Set` and `Delete` are implemented similar to the standard binary search tree functions for adding/removing from the tree (these can be found [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion)). The only difference is that now an insertion or a deletion might trigger rotating the tree to ensure the heap invariant.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets/Replaces node located at child.key in root 
    /// and rebalances the tree if necessary
    /// </summary>
    private Node Set(Node root, Node child)
    {
        if (root == null) return child;

        int cmp = child.Key.CompareTo(root.Key);
        if (cmp == 0)
            return child;
        else if (cmp > 0)
        {
            root.Right = Set(root.Right, child);
            if (root.Right.Priority < root.Priority)
                root = LRotate(root);
        }
        else if (cmp < 0)
        {
            root.Left = Set(root.Left, child);
            if (root.Left.Priority < root.Priority)
                root = RRotate(root);
        }
        return root;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes key from root by demoting it down to a leaf
    /// and rebalances the tree if necessary
    /// </summary>
    private Node Delete(Node root, TKey key)
    {
        if (root == null) return null;

        int cmp = key.CompareTo(root.Key);
        if (cmp < 0) root.Left  = Delete(root.Left, key);
        if (cmp > 0) root.Right = Delete(root.Right, key);
        if (cmp== 0)
        {
            if (root.Left != null && root.Right != null)
            {
                if (root.Left.Priority < root.Right.Priority)
                    root = RRotate(root); 
                else
                    root = LRotate(root); 
            }
            else if (root.Left  != null) root = RRotate(root);
            else if (root.Right != null) root = LRotate(root);
            else return null;
            root = Delete(root, key);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

I'm wondering if my tree rotation methods can be improved. Should I make the `Nodes` in the tree immutable, and return a new rotated `Node` instead?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Promotes the right child to root 
    /// (i.e. rotate the "right child" left)
    /// </summary>
    private Node LRotate(Node root)
    {
        Node temp = root.Right;
        root.Right = temp.Left;
        temp.Left = root;
        return temp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Promotes the left child to root 
    /// (i.e. rotate the "left child" right)
    /// </summary>
    private Node RRotate(Node root)
    {
        Node temp = root.Left;
        root.Left = temp.Right;
        temp.Right = root;
        return temp;
    }
```

Finally, my code provides validation. This is intended for testing purposes only, though I'm not sure how this should be exposed to a test project without making `Node` internal and then [exposing the project's internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440935/how-to-test-internal-class-library). Maybe there's no better way.

```
    /// <summary>Performs an in-order traversal from root</summary>
    private IEnumerable<Node> InOrder(Node root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            yield break;

        foreach (Node child in InOrder(root.Left).Append(root).Concat(InOrder(root.Right)))
            yield return child;
    }

    /// <summary>Validates the min-heap order for root</summary>
    private bool IsHeap(Node root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            return true;
        if (root.Right != null && root.Right.Priority < root.Priority)
            return false;
        if (root.Left  != null && root.Left.Priority  < root.Priority)
            return false;
        return IsHeap(root.Left) && IsHeap(root.Right);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the heap order and bst order
    /// properties are satisfied
    /// </summary>
    public bool AssertTreap()
    {
        return root == null ? true :
            InOrder(root).SequenceEqual(InOrder(root).OrderBy(x => x.Key)) && IsHeap(root); 
    }
```

I've defined`Append` in an extension method

```
internal static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
    {
        foreach (T x in source)
            yield return x;
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

### Example of use

Here's a simple test that can be run in the debugger.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new BinaryTreap<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            t[i] = i;


        bool valid = t.AssertTreap();

        t.Delete(1);
        try
        {
            int one = t[1];
        }
        catch
        {
            // doesn't exist
        }
    }
}
```

### What I'd like reviewed

- Better (more functional) implementations of `RotateR` and `RotateL`?
- How should I expose `Node` to a test project? Right now I have my validation code in the class itself which doesn't seem right. I don't want to mark `Node` internal; is there a better way to expose the underlying data structure for testing purposes?

### Edit

Here is the `Get` method used by the indexer.

```
    /// <summary>Retrieves Node located at key by binary search</summary>
    private Node Get(Node root, TKey key)
    {
        if (root == null) return null;

        int cmp = key.CompareTo(root.Key);
        if (cmp < 0) return Get(root.Left, key);
        if (cmp > 0) return Get(root.Right, key);
        return root;
    }
```

Here is the public wrapper for `Delete`.

```
    public void Delete(TKey key)
    {
        root = Delete(root, key);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

1. It would be nice to be able to pass an [`IComparer<TKey>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of having to make sure `TKey` implements `IComparable<>`. It could default to [`Comparer<TKey>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This provides you with a lot more flexibility in terms of which types can be used as keys.
2. `Get` can return `null` . So if you try to access a non-existing key you will get a `NullReferenceException` which is typically not very meaningful. The indexer should protect against that and throw a [`KeyNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.
3. Related to the previous point you may want to consider implementing a `TryGet` method similar to what other data structure implementations in the .NET framework provide.
4. Regarding the validation code: I don't think the validation code should live in the data structure. What I'd do is to make `BinaryTreap` implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` with the enumerator doing a in-order traversal, but instead of yielding the node it yields a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` with the data. This way you can write the validation code as a unit test.
   The `IsHeap` one is a bit more tricky. Need to think about that one.